# Create a link so that information across multiple rows can be matched to a unique ID, and will be sorted/filtered based on that?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, links

So I want to be able to link the ingredients for Pizza (Flour, Tomatoes, Pepperoni) to the Unique ID, 1. If I sort or put a filter on the ID column so only show '1', I want all the ingredients to appear, not just Flour.

I'd also have the rows under ID and Food merged for each ingredient. So essentially I want to create sub-rows and have the sub-rows linked to the Unique ID.

Is this possible to do?

[image: Excel Table]

Answer (score 0):

> So essentially I want to create sub-rows and have the sub-rows linked to the Unique ID.
>   Is this possible to do?

It as you describe it.

You can create your raw data in a table without merged cells and each row containing the IDs.

Then create a pivot table based on that which you can order and filter as needed.